# Aggregating based on previous year and this year

Tags: r, aggregate

I have these data sets

```
month Year Rain  
10    2010 376.8  
11    2010 282.78  
12    2010 324.58  
1     2011 73.51    
2     2011 225.89  
3     2011 22.96
```

I used

```
df2prnext<-
  aggregate(Rain~Year, data = subdataprnext, mean)
```

but I need the mean value of 217.53.

I am not getting the expected result. Thank you for your help.

Comment: it would help to tag this with the appropriate language (c, Excel, R, Java, etc)

Comment: Thanks for the response. These one is written in R

Comment: Thank you guys. I solved it.